# Detect data type of value in Windows Registry Key with Java

Tags: java, registry

Is it possible to detect the type of a value stored in a Windows registry key using java?

I tried instanceof but that falls short.

I need to be able to detect if a key value is of any of these types:
Binary, DWord, SZ, None, Link, QWord, Multi SZ, Expand SZ, Resource List, Full Resource Descriptor, Resource Requirements List

Thanks

Comment: [I downvoted because without code to see what you tried, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Comment: I could post about 50 pages of code I tried.  Nothing worked.  Nothing came close to working.  That's why I asked the way I did.  I couldn't care less about the down vote.  Actual help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process processIn = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query " + '"'+ regKey + "\" /v " + regSubKey);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(processIn.getInputStream());
reader.start();
reader.join();
String read = reader.getResult();

String[] parsed = reader.getResult().split("\\s+");
if (parsed.length > 1) {
    read = parsed[parsed.length-2];
    System.out.println("type = " + read)
}
```

Define regKey and regSubKey and this snippet works. There may be a way to do this cleaner but it works for what I need.